# Need help to set DWORD value with python

Tags: python, winreg

I am trying to set a `DWORD` value of `0xFFFFFFFF` in Windows registry.
But when I try this:

```
_winreg.SetValueEx(aKey,"dword_test_2",0, _winreg.REG_DWORD, 4294967295L )
```

it throws an error:

> ValueError: Could not convert the data to the specified type.

Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, using the `L` suffix to a number creates a value of type `long`. The `long` is an [integer of arbitrary size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic). The `DWORD` likely corresponds to an `int` in Python.

Did you try

```
_winreg.SetValueEx(aKey,"dword_test_2",0, _winreg.REG_DWORD, 0xFFFFFFFF )
```

or

```
_winreg.SetValueEx(aKey,"dword_test_2",0, _winreg.REG_DWORD, -1 )
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Oh yeah, this. I think you need to use `-1` instead.